# Call events from the main function

Tags: c++, qt

I was used, in java, to create events almost anywhere, but in c++ (**Qt**), I notice that you have to create a class to be able to use the object's events. My question is the following : would it be possible to use `MouseEvent` (or any other event) belonging to a `QPushButton` from the main function ?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    QWidget window;

    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton("Add",&window);

    //Here, an event related to 'btn' to update the window...

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**PS : I know it's better to use the Qt Designer form, but I'm just asking about the possibility of doing this task.**

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: That was pre-C++11.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks, did not know that. Can you share an example of the usage?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX: See the new overload `QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, Functor functor)` . Lambda's are functors, they have an `operator()`. But `std::function<>` also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt offers the [signal & slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) mechanism. You can simply connect the `QPushButton::clicked()` signal to a slot that then performs the update you're referring to.

Using C++11's lambda:

```cpp
// Create pushbutton
QPushButton* btn = nw QPushButton("Add",&window);

// Connect slot to 'clicked' signal
QObject::connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, []{
    qDebug("Button clicked!");
    // ... whatever else you want to happen on a button click
});
```

Keep in mind that you have other problems in your code as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: But `this`doesn't exist in the main context

Comment: I agree. Small mistake that was in the meantime corrected by someone else!

Answer (score 3):

Some events, e.g. mouse movement or focus changes, are not accessible through slots/signals.

You can use a small proxy QObject to filter events for other objects. [See `installEventFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) for a code sample. You don't need to actually filter the events; you may just listen in and let them pass through.

Likewise, you can trigger/fake an event manually through `QCoreApplication` via [`notify()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#notify).

Answer (score 2):

As Joel Bodenmann notes, Qt uses signals and slots. You can have a slot on a `QObject`, but Qt can also connect to a lambda. Your lambda would have to capture `window` by reference, so it can update the window.

You'd probably want to connect the `clicked` event.

Comment: `MouseEvent` is not propagated through signal/slot. There is a method for it in the widget class.

Comment: @ypnos: Fair point, made explicit that there's a proper signal.